# disallow the line break while reading in a number in c++?

Tags: c++, input

I have a problem.
i want the user to enter a number in my c++ program, but during the input i want to prevent that he just presses enter without having made an input, thus creating a line break.

I have already solved the problem in another place where the user has to enter a character.
I have read the character with getchar, determined the position of the cursor with the ANSI escape sequences and provided the whole thing with a do while loop.

But since I want to read in a number between 0 and 250, getchar would not be suitable.
scanf and cin both wait for a valid input and cause these nasty line breaks.

I have already thought about using getchar anyway and storing the characters in a char array whose indices I then convert to the corresponding numbers which I then add up to the actual number which can then be stored again in an int variable.
But surely there is an easier alternative or?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: 'Surely there is an easier alternative'. I don't think so. Sometimes you have to do the work yourself.

Comment: To do that you need to control the keyboard device directly rather than standard I/O. That's not a functionality offered by the c++ standard library.

Answer (score 0):

This line will flush the newline character

```
cin.ignore(256, '\n');
```

Comment: but this only empties the keyboard buffer, right?